# GRUB issue during Parrot OS (Debian based) installation on Virtual Box

Tags: linux, debian, grub

Installing Parrot OS on Virtual Box with Windows 10 as host. Installation, gets complete without installing GRUB or LILO boot loader. Seems common issue, in various Linux forums, due to Debian bug.

During installation, network is auto-disconnecting and probably due to this, boot loader is not getting installed.

1. Is it possible to enable networking, during installation. (Tried, but doesn't work, it remains disabled always).
2. How to install boot loader safely, without re-installation.
3. And how to manual start OS as informed in below post-installation message:

> You will need to boot manually with the /vmlinuz kernel on partition
>   /dev/sda5 and root=/dev/sda5 passed as kernel argument

Answer (score 0):

This is just an issue when you try to install in graphical mode. 
Choose in bootmenue the option for textbased installationmode and grub will be installed without problems.